# Add controls to Stackpanel at runtime (SL 4.0)

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, stackpanel

I have a user control that contains a stackpanel.

I'm trying to find a way to bind the children of the stackpanel to aproperty so that I can access them from another control

Anyone has any clue how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using DataBinding, then enable a binding override your stackpanel with an itemsControl. Then you can work with the collection property named ItemsProperty

```
<StackPanel>
   <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" >
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" /> <!-- you could also use Border -->
              </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

---

If you are in the codebehind, you don't need to override the ItemsControl, just call stackpanel1.Children.Add(item); (if x:Name="stackpanel1" in XAML).

Then stackPanel1.Children should have elements.

Comment: I've called the stackpanel.childern.add(item) but the added item(s) don't apppear on the control

Comment: Are you using Binding or codebehind? I edited my answer to hopefully make it more clear. If you added a code snippet I might be able to give you a more precise answer.

Comment: usercontrolA.xaml:                                         <Stackpanel Margin="78,0,16,16" Height="469" x:Name="ChartArea"/>. usercontrolA.xaml.cs:                                          public FrameworkElement Chart
        {
            set 
            {
                ChartArea.children.add(value);
            }
        }                                                                   in usercontrolB.xaml.cs: ((usercontrolA).Chart = new ListBox();

Comment: Try creating a property in the userControlA of public ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> Charts (instead of your Chart property). Then in userControlB.xaml.cs : userControlA.Charts.Add(new ListBox());. Then use the ItemsControl idea and bind to the Charts property.

Comment: Thanks! I 've followed your gude and the items get added! Unfortunetely though they don't render (appear) on the control

Comment: Progress is good :-). Now I think you need to look closer at the DataTemplate. I edited it (in my answer) to better reflect your situation.